# Simple addition of 1 to a large number does not work? (Python 3.9)

Tags: python, prime-factoring

Note: I am not that experienced in Python, therefore my code may not be as good as it could/should be.

I am attempting to create a tool to facilitate calculating the algebraic factors of a certain form of number (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurifeuillean_factorization). This is mostly as a test/learning experience, however I have run into a problem when attempting to calculate the parameter "c", which is defined as 2^(2k+1)+1. The addition step does not work for me. I am simply getting the returned value as 2^129, instead of 2^129+1 as I am looking to get. Is this an issue with Python itself, or am I making some sort of mistake in this.

Code:

```
import math


def make_aurifeuille_factors(base, exponent):
    if base == 2 and exponent % 4 == 2:
        k = (exponent - 2) / 4
        c = int(1 + 2 ** (2*k + 1))
        d = int(2 ** (k + 1))
        L = c + d
        M = c - d

        return int(k), int(c), int(d), int(L), int(M)


def gcd(a, b):
    return int(math.gcd(a, b))


print(make_aurifeuille_factors(2, 258))
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to see as output vs what you see? Python supports infinite (within machine constraints) precision for its int type.

Comment: I am looking to (if possible) be handling numbers upwards of 1000 digits. I am expecting the value of "c" to be 680564733841876926926749214863536422913, where I am getting 680564733841876926926749214863536422912 instead. The addition of 1 at the end does not seem to actually get added.

Comment: The answer given by @Julien is correct. I would add one thing: since k is a float, it makes `2 ** (2*k + 1)` a float. You then add 1 to a float, which has limited precision, and convert it to int, which shows the reduced precision.

Comment: @Plutie: The intermediate value is `float`, which is a C `double`, and typically has only 53 bits of integer precision. If you're doing large number work, you *never* let yourself go to floating point land. All those `int()` wrappers you put in are hiding your mistakes with types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`k = (exponent - 2) / 4` makes `k` a `float`, which means you potentially introduce numerical error in computations down the line. Use integer division to stay in `int` world from the start:

```
def make_aurifeuille_factors(base, exponent):
    if base == 2 and exponent % 4 == 2:
        k = (exponent - 2) // 4
        c = 1 + 2 ** (2*k + 1)
        d = 2 ** (k + 1)
        L = c + d
        M = c - d

        return k, c, d, L, M
```

Comment: You can also see this is definitely the problem, as pulling the `1+` outside of the `int()` function also fixes the problem.

Comment: Also note: You could simplify to `k = exponent // 4`; the `if` confirms it's exactly `2 mod 4`, so you don't need to subtract `2`, you can just `// 4` and the floor division will take care of the extra `2`.

Comment: @Turksarama: It might, in some cases. But any time you take big integers and work with them as `float`s, you're introducing an opportunity for error; never leave `int`-land when you want `int` inputs and outputs (and it'll be faster to boot; no need for all that pointless wrapping with `int()` to coerce back, hiding errors).

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem. I will try to keep that in mind for the next time I run into this issue. (will most likely happen again.)